# How to add all X and Y Axis Lines in Visual C# Graphs

Tags: c#, graph, visual-c#-express-2010

I'm working on making  my life a little easier in math, so I'm making a quick program that will graph points I put in. It's all going fine, except that by default the graphs will not put the axis lines it does not use. For example, if I graph (2,-10)(7,-8)(-4,5), it will only put the X axis lines I am using.

Here's an example: http://prntscr.com/21t0j9 (you can see that the labeled lines on the bottom are 2, 7, and -4).

In short, how would I make every X and Y axis line appear? Because now it only puts lines for the points I'm using on the X axis, and the Y axis just counts by 5's.

Thanks

Comment: If it's all in integers, loop around each of them.

Comment: @John I'm relatively new to C#. I know what loops are and everything, but could you go into more detail about how I would use them in this instance?
Thanks, Nash.

Answer (score 0):

Try a `foreach` loop.

```
foreach int x in myIntArray{
// do your printing, etc.
}
```